# Program flow issues in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I am parsing a json to display the contents in the tableview. I have the array containing parsed json being populated in getReceivedData which is called after the UITAbleView Delegate methods. So it is problem in populating tableview as when the compiler attempts to populate it the array is not yet initialized.

```
- (void)getReceivedData:(NSMutableData *)data sender:(RestAPI *)sender{

NSError * error=nil;
NSArray *receivedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
NSString *dictionaryKey=@"department";
NSString *predicateString=@"software";
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" %K == %@ ", dictionaryKey,predicateString];
NSArray *shortlisted=[receivedData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
for(int i = 0; i<shortlisted.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *detailItems=[shortlisted objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *name=[detailItems objectForKey:@"emp_name"];
    NSString *designation=[detailItems objectForKey:@"designation"];
    NSString *email=[detailItems objectForKey:@"email"];
    NSString *phone_no=[detailItems objectForKey:@"phone_no"];
  //  NSString *image=[detailItems objectForKey:@"url_path"];
    dictionary1=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
               name, @"keyname",
                designation, @"keydesignation",
                email, @"keyid",
                phone_no, @"keyphone",

               nil];
     [myObject1 addObject:dictionary1];
   }

 }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
(NSInteger)section{
   if(isfiltered==YES){
       return [filteredArray count];
  }
   else{
  return [myObject1 count];
   }

 }
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

MyTableCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
if(!cell){
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyTableCell" bundle:nil] 
forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
}


if(isfiltered==NO)
{
  NSDictionary * tmpdict= [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpdict objectForKeyedSubscript:@"keyname"]];
    cell.designationLabel.text=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpdict objectForKeyedSubscript:@"keydesignation"]];
    cell.idLabel.text=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpdict objectForKeyedSubscript:@"keyid"]];
    cell.phoneLabel.text=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpdict objectForKeyedSubscript:@"keyphone"]];
    cell.mainImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[tmpdict objectForKeyedSubscript:@"keyimage"]];

}
else{
    NSDictionary * tmpdict= [filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpdict objectForKeyedSubscript:@"keyname"]];
    cell.designationLabel.text=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpdict objectForKeyedSubscript:@"keydesignation"]];
    cell.idLabel.text=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpdict objectForKeyedSubscript:@"keyid"]];
    cell.phoneLabel.text=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpdict objectForKeyedSubscript:@"keyphone"]];
             cell.mainImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[tmpdict objectForKeyedSubscript:@"keyimage"]];
      }
   return cell;


}
```

[image]
This window was supposed to view the table

Comment: `@"%@",name,@"keyname",` => `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name], @"keyname"`, and so one. ? Or simply `NSString *name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[detailItems objectForKey:@"emp_name"]]; and `name,@"keyname"` (without the "%@").

Comment: simply change like `dictionary1=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                name,@"keyname",
                designation,@"keydesignation",
                email,@"keyid",
                phone_no,@"keyphone",
               nil];`

Comment: @Larme thank you so much

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thank u so much .. it worked again

Comment: @AashimaAnand - are you get the array of dictionary correct, then why you chnaged again , directly used your array of dictionary where you need

Comment: Note that if any of `name`, `designation`, `email` or `phone_no` is nil (doesn't exist in `detailItems`), the following keys/objects won't be present in your dictionary with the others answers. That's why I used `stringWithFormat:` (`NSNull` could be used too).

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have is populated the array myObject1  in getReceivedData method and the UITableView Delegate methods are called before getReceivedData. The UITableView is to be populated by myObject1... Please help me

Comment: @AashimaAnand - can you update the question , it is easy to answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have updated the questions please let me know if you encounter difficulties in understanding it

Comment: @AashimaAnand  - simple , after this  `[myObject1 addObject:dictionary1];
   } if (myObject1.count > 0) { [yourtableview reloaddata]; }`

Comment: @AashimaAnand - do fast my sister,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I am so sorry I just saw your reply . I did what u suggested but nothing happened. I am attaching the screenshot. Please help.

Comment: @AashimaAnand - where is the screen shot

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  I have edited the question .It is there

Comment: @AashimaAnand - show your full code

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
this is the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148268/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-aashima-anand).

Answer (score 4):

In a mutable dictionary first you have to give object then its key. You are doing wrong

```
for(int i = 0; i<shortlisted.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *detailItems=[shortlisted objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *name=[detailItems objectForKey:@"emp_name"];
    NSString *designation=[detailItems objectForKey:@"designation"];
    NSString *email=[detailItems objectForKey:@"email"];
    NSString *phone_no=[detailItems objectForKey:@"phone_no"];


dictionary1=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                name,@"keyname",
                designation,@"keydesignation",
                email,@"keyid",
                phone_no,@"keyphone",
               nil];
 [myObject1 addObject:dictionary1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not correct way to intialize dictionary as you did, @"%@" is used %@ is a placeholder in a format string for any object.

```
dictionary1=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                name,@"keyname",
                designation,@"keydesignation",
                email,@"keyid",
                phone_no,@"keyphone",
               nil];
```